# 2 perl installations. (v5.18.2) and (v5.10.1) I just want one

Tags: perl, ubuntu, installation, cpan

I force installed a cpan module and to my surprise it installed the latest perl version 5.18.2. (I didn't anticipate, nor wanted this to happen) How can I get rid of v5.18.2?

More Info
Ubuntu Server 10.04.4,
Module File::Basename,
Means command-line cpan

Comment: What module was it?  What means did you use to install it?

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't easy....or when I call the perl compiler, how can I get it to call the 5.10.1 version instead of version 5.18.2? anything helps.

Comment: We don't have enough information.  Was the new version installed over the old version, upgrading your system Perl?  You used "sudo"?  Or was it installed somewhere else, locally?  If you've upgraded your system Perl, roll back to a previous backup of your system.

Comment: No the new version wasn't installed over the old version. It is installed somewhere else locally. I used sudo. I'm using a proprietary server. I'm not sure they would allow me to roll back to a previous version using the backup. I'll inquire.

Comment: If it was installed elsewhere, find where it is: `which perl`, or `locate bin/perl`, for example.  Remove its directory structure.  Remove it from your path.  ...but be absolutely sure it hasn't replaced your system Perl first, and do a backup first.

Comment: Re "do a backup first". Most definitely. You can do this by renaming the directory instead of actually removing it at first.

Comment: If you're a `perlbrew` user, I can show you how to switch between the system Perl and your local Perl easily. Let me know if this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks at @DavidO

Checked which version of perl was being found.

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/usr/bin$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux
```

Checked the system perl to ensure that v5.18.2 didn't overwrite it. Looks like it didn't.

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/usr/bin$ /usr/bin/perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Located where v5.18.2 is located.

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/usr/bin$ which perl
/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Double checked with the previous path that this was indeed the location of v5.18.2

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/usr/bin$ /usr/local/bin/perl -v
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux
```

Removed it.

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/usr/local/bin$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/perl
```

Whoo Hoo!

```
ionadmin@ion-torrent-server:/$ perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```